# How to make Sublime Text stop asking me to reload every file

Tags: sublime-text-2

I had several thousand files open in a Sublime Text project and those files were modified outside of Sublime so it started prompting me whether or not I wanted to reload the file or cancel.  But if I hit *Cancel* it continues to display the same prompt for every file.  I tried to force quit Sublime but when I relaunch it, it relaunches with the same files open and again it begins to prompt me about reloading the files.  I would literally have to sit here holding down the Enter key for hours to get all of these prompts to pass..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by manually deleting the files that Sublime Text saves session data to.. These files were

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Auto Save Session.sublime_session`
`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session`

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting you can apply in ST3 to disable the prompt for auto-reloading:

```
{
    "always_prompt_for_file_reload": false
}
```

Go to Preferences > Settings, and merge the above into your settings JSON. Note, this setting does not *prevent* the files from reloading, it just stops asking you about it. There is currently no setting to completely disable the auto-reload.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have the configuration set, but I'm still getting the prompt.